# Meaning to the phrase "last year's man"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I saw this in a Leonard Cohen's lyrics. I wonder if it means anything in particular in the English language.

Comment: You should include the title of the song and quote a longer section of the lyrics for context.

Comment: Sorry, the first question ever. Yes, I can indeed. "The rain falls down on last year's man." The song is called 'Last Year's man', from the Songs of Love and Hate record.

Comment: It's a fair question, but the answer, I think, is that there is no generalized sense in English of "last year's man" as a set phrase. Cohen's meaning is contextually discernible (arguably), but it is his own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to 'last years fashion', a man who was popular and successful last year, but is now no longer relevant.

Comment: Thank you, my friend. I leave you here with a bit more, but I get what you said. "The rain falls down on last year's man. That's a Jew's harp on the table
That's a crayon in his hand." That is the first verse, later he says "And the skylight is like skin for a drum I'll never mend.
And all the rain falls down amen.
On the works of last year's man."

Comment: The song might have more to do with the singer's personal state than success or fashion – it could mean that they haven't moved on emotionally. But it's a matter of opinion what song lyrics mean.